# Git, multiple location code into single repo

Tags: git, github

I have two servers, where same code is placed. Server 1 and Server 2.

From server 1, I initialized the git and placed the code into repo successfully.

Now, I want to connect server 2 code also to this repo. Not sure, how can I do it without deleting the code in any server.

Comment: Though question is unclear,  reposync from Android might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is the same you could just clone your repository into Server 2:

```
git clone git@my.git.server/my-code.git
```

Future updates could be obtained by simply doing a git pull.

Comment: Is there a way, I can use the same code already exist on server 2 and make it a repo?

Comment: Are you trying to create/maintain two separate code bases or do you want to have exactly the same code on both running on machines?

But yes you can. Simply run `git init && git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"` and you'll have the code of server 2 on a local git repo.

Comment: Both server are running, so I can't delete the code from any server

Comment: Well there are ways you can do the swap between your code on server 2 and the code stored in git on server 1, but it depends on what this code does and what your, i'll suppose, web stack is made of and setup.